# why the setIsrunning(false) method ‘s caller is "main" Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Run {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        RunThreas runThreas=new RunThreas();
        runThreas.start();
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        runThreas.setIsrunning(false);
        System.out.println("已经赋值为false");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}


class RunThreas extends Thread{

private boolean isrunning=true;

public boolean isRunning(){
    return isrunning;
}

public void setIsrunning(boolean isrunning){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"set");
    this.isrunning=isrunning;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"run");
    System.out.println("进入run");
    while(isrunning){
        System.out.println("i am running");
    }

    System.out.println("线程被停止了");
}
}
```

the `setIsrunnning()` method belongs to `Runthread`,so I think it should be called by instanse of `Runthread`, but actually it is invoked by Thread "main". I want to know it's why?

Comment: Because it's the line after starting the thread in the `main` method. If it should be started in the other `Thread`, then you should set it in the `run` method of the other `Thread`.

Comment: thanks，I make it complex myself，and i get it now